# Why Download a file by jQuery.Ajax (plugin by John Culviner) is not working for URL with querystring in IE10/11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to download a pdf file with _CONV_ID as querystring parameter; using John Culviner File Download plugin but not working:

```
<a href="./cbufile/cbudetails.pdf?_CONV_ID=${_CONV_ID}" class="fileDownload" >Download CBU Details</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.fileDownload", function () {
  var link = $(this).prop('href');
  $.fileDownload(link);
```

Server Side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "cbufile/cbudetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<byte[]> CBUDetails(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
  @ModelAttribute("CBUForm") CBUFormform) {
```

This link with Query String as _CONV_ID is not working for IE-10, IE11 but links without querystrings are working fine.

Could anyone provide alternative for the same?

Comment: havent used the plugin, but i noticed that the website says specifically that it supports ie 6-9. could be broken on newer IE versions. but your ${_CONV_ID} parameter that doesnt seem to be getting replaced seems like a red flag. is something in the pipeline expecting this value to be set?

Comment: Yes. It is get call in which we need to put conversation ID to remain in session